# Django Template Filters on Session Values?

Tags: python, django, session

Is there a way to use Django Template Filters on session values?

I have sessions with date and time and would like to use template filters to display them in different format.

My session time value is: `18:30` and would like to display as `6:30PM`.

This is not working:

```
{{ request.session.mytime|time:"g:iA" }}
```

Date formatting also not working. Stored in session as `12/14/2014`

```
{{ request.session.mydate|date:"M d, Y" }}
```

Assuming the session values are not stored correctly as date or time?

If so, what is the proper format to store date and time in sessions?

Comment: How about converting date and time in your view, and store them as a text string?

Comment: I could probably do that but then, I would have to do the same for every view where I want to use this session. Obviously I can store the session values in desired format but this was more about the filter functionality with sessions.

Comment: @sax Django version 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django > 1.5 does not use pickle, so any value when serialized loose its type. So you are right: session values are not stored as date type. Store the values already formatted for your needs should solve the issue

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization